# upload to bucket cannot be completed

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created a bucket in (trial version) but cannot transfer any files. The option is grayed out and if I drag a file or files to bucket I get "Upload cannot be completed" "you don't have permission to upload files to this bucket" I have added myself as "storage legacy object owner", "storage object admin" and "storage object creator"

Comment: Does the command `gsutil cp my_file gs://$BUCKET_NAME/` work for you?